# QGIS find steepest path on a DEM [Path of a drop of water]

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

Is there an algorithm or plugin in QGIS to find the steepest path on a DEM given a point (the path followed by a drop of water)?

Comment: Look at the QGIS hydrological analysis training, maybe it has what you want : https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/processing/hydro.html

Comment: I have looked at it. It does not have what I want.